# Are semicolon-terminated if-statements good coding practice?

Tags: c++, coding-style

I am looping i, j, k and n. I want a statement to execute except when `k == j` and `n == k`.

If I use the code like this:

```
if (k != j && n != i)
      //statement
```

The statement will not execute in two cases:

1. When k != j when n == j.
2. When k == j when n != j.  (*which is not what I need*)

So I used a code like this:

```
if (k == j && n == i)
    ;else
    //statement
```

By this code the statement will successfully execute except when `k == j && n == i`.

Is semicolon-terminated if-statements is a good way of coding in C++?

Comment: Why not just negate the condition? If it's unpleasant to the eye, perhaps the DeMorganized version will help.

Comment: `if (!(k==j && n==i))` should do the same i think, but i do not know much c\c++ so don't hold me to that.

Comment: @chris @M4rtini `if (!(k==j && n==i))` This will definitely work. I am new to coding so excuse my question. Semicolon Terminated If Statement in c++ is a good way of coding?

Comment: It's a terrible way of coding.

Comment: If you're really looking to do it (e.g., because of something like `if (a); else if (b) {...} else if (c) {...} else {...}`), you might as well replace the semicolon in the first with empty braces so the compiler won't complain, or move the semicolon to a new line (at least Clang likes that).

Comment: @chris : tried it with empty brazes{} 100% successful. But using `if (!(k==j && n==i))` would be better right?

Comment: @owleye, Yes, there's really no reason (under normal circumstances) to have an empty if and then an else.

Comment: i have seen code like `if(false) ; else if(...) ... else if(...)` for the reason to keep all the "real" tests aligned, I think. Could also be managed by `.....if(...) ... else if(...) ...` but perhaps it would be dedendet automatically...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it's not a good way of coding.  The usual way is to use `!` to invert the logic:

```
if(!(k==j && n==i))
    //statement
```

Or you could use [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to invert the logic:

```
if(k!=j || n!=i)
    //statement
```

Comment: you're missing a closing parenthesis in the first code example.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that you're negating the condition incorrectly. You should just do:

```
if (!(k==j && n==i))
  // statement
```

Or, by De Morgan's laws:

```
if (k != j || n != i)
  // statement
```

Answer (score 1):

> ... is a good way of coding?

No.

You should write

```
if (!(k == j && n == 1))
{
    //statement
}
```

Putting a semicolon after an `if`, `for`, or `while` is almost always wrong. It is highly unexpected and makes reading your code very difficult.